# window.screenX inconsistencies in Windows 10 with Electron (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, windows, electron

I'm trying to locate the center point of an element relative to the entire screen, and for that I'm using window.screenX and window.screenY to calculate the position of the window on the screen.

I'm seeing very weird inconsistencies with window.screenX and I'm not sure what the cause is.

If my window is maximized, it returns 0 as expected.

However if my window is not maximized and the window is on the edge of the screen, it returns -7.

In fullscreen mode both window.screenX and window.screenY return 8.

As you can imagine this throws off my center point, and I'm really at a loss at what is causing this. Is this a Windows specific issue? A bug of some kind? Are there other ways I can go about grabbing the center point of an element relative to the screen?

Thank you for the help.

Edit: I thought it could be something to do with the window shadows in Windows 10. I turned off the shadows but still get the same results.

Edit2: For anyone that might read this later, this is not exclusive to Electron. A workaround (but not ideal) could be removing the window frame. I'm open to any more suggestions.

Comment: have you tried pageX and pageY

Comment: Do you mean pageXOffset? Or event.pageX? I believe both are relative to the document and not the screen.

Comment: if you are planning to do it relative to the screen. i think there is a method for that when you make an instance of `BrowserWindow`. or you can use the screen object in electron'

Comment: win.getBounds() seems to be returning the same issue. I did find something that's a little odd. If I make the window frameless when creating the BrowserWindow, the issue goes away and I get the values I expect. It seems to me Windows does some funky stuff to the window when there is a frame. I'm not sure if this is only in Windows 10 or if it's repeatable elsewhere.